# iMac Lion not logging in

Tags: macos, mac, imac, login, safe-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iMac not logging probably due to keychains problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/imac-not-logging-probably-due-to-keychains-problem)

iMac OS X Lion here.

I have two accounts in the iMac. Both with password.

I'm not sure what happened, but now, when I startup the iMac, when I try to enter the first account, I enter the password, the screen goes blank for a moment, and throws me back to the login screen. No messages pop up.

But I CAN enter my second account.

What am I supposed to do?

---

**Edit: More info**
I remember I was messing with that account's keychain stuff (keys/certificates/etc), possibly deleting keys or even replacing them with other keys etc... Maybe that's related.

Answer (score 1):

The first step in troubleshooting this problem is to boot into Safe Mode.

Shut your Mac down, and press the power button. As soon as you hear the startup sound, hold down the left Shift key. Keep holding it down until the spinning clock appears.

Starting up will take longer than normal because the Mac is performing some basic disk repair procedures.

Once startup is complete, and you are back to the Finder, reboot the Mac again.

If this does not solve the problem, it is time to try the next step.

Comment: Hey, I think I know *why* I am having this problem. But I had to open a new question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/imac-not-logging-probably-due-to-keychains-problem

Can you help me there? I'm closing this one. Thank you.